# In MySQL table selecting only when a field is not empty or not ' '

Tags: php, mysql

my majority of values are filled but set_price column has few empty field. i want to select only when set_price is not empty or not ''. i am using mysql and datatype set for set price is `set_price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

**MY Function:**

```
 function getAvilableServiceDetails($service_id,$select_from,$select_to,$select_weight,$dimesion_height,$dimesion_width,$dimesion_girth,$price_shorting)
            {
                global $objSmarty;  

        //  echo $service_id."//".$select_from."//".$select_to."//".$select_weight."//".$dimesion_height."//".$dimesion_width."//".$dimesion_girth."//".$price_shorting; exit;

                if($select_weight=='')
                    $select_weight=0;

                if($dimesion_height!='')
                $height_condition=" and  dimesion_height>=".$dimesion_height;
                else
                $height_condition="";

                if($dimesion_width!='')
                $width_condition="  and  dimesion_width>=".$dimesion_width;
                else
                $width_condition="";

                if($dimesion_girth!='')
                $girth_condition=" and dimesion_girth>=".$dimesion_girth;
                else
                $girth_condition="";



                //===================searching condition=========================//
                    if($_SESSION['package_search_by']!='')
                        $searching_condition=" and service_type='".$_SESSION['package_search_by']."'";
                    else
                        $searching_condition="";    

                //=====================price shorting============================//
                if($price_shorting!='')
                {
                    if($price_shorting=='L_TO_H')
                        $order_by=" group by unique_id order by set_price ASC ";
                    else    
                        $order_by=" group by unique_id order by set_price DESC ";
                }
                else
                {
                    $order_by=" group by unique_id order by set_price ASC ";
                }

                if($select_from!='' && $select_to!='' && $service_id!='')
                {
                   $select_query="select * from set_delivery_package_details  where service_id='".$service_id."' and 
                    dimesion_weight>=".$select_weight." and set_price IS NOT NULL and set_price<>'' and FIND_IN_SET ('".$select_from."',sel_countrys) and FIND_IN_SET ('".$select_to."',sel_countrys)  and deleted='N' and status='Y' ".$searching_condition.$height_condition.$width_condition.$girth_condition.$order_by;
                    $this->dbh->Query($select_query);
                    if($this->dbh->num_rows>0)
                    {
                        $PackageData=$this->dbh->FetchAllResults($select_query);
                        $objSmarty->assign("PackageData", $PackageData);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $searching_error_message="Record Not Found";
                        $objSmarty->assign("searching_error_message", $searching_error_message);
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    $searching_error_message="Record Not Found Please Search Again";
                    $objSmarty->assign("searching_error_message", $searching_error_message);
                }
            }
```

**The table which i am using:** [please click here](http://s17.postimg.org/t73wz9qdb/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: no error but still the result is printed even after set_price is empty

Comment: not even one of your else statements

Comment: see i put the full function above, if set_price is empty i.e. ' ' i should get "record not found" but its not working its giving the output, when i tried other way round by setting set_price to any other value say 25 and then checked as set_price='foo' in query. its working, and gave "record not found". how to do the same in first case.

Comment: try to assign a variable to the query so `$this->query = $this->dbh->Query($select_query);` then afterwards pull all methods fro the `$this->query` object.

Comment: appoh, really newbie in the programming and was playing with the codes, what you said i understood but confused, please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work!

```
$select_query = 
    "SELECT * 
     FROM set_delivery_package_details  
     WHERE service_id='".$service_id."' 
       AND dimesion_weight>=".$select_weight." 
       AND (set_price != NULL
           OR set_price != ''
           OR set_price IS NOT NULL
           OR set_price <> '') 
       AND FIND_IN_SET ('".$select_from."',sel_countrys) 
       AND FIND_IN_SET ('".$select_to."',sel_countrys)  
       AND deleted='N' 
       AND status='Y' "
     .$searching_condition
     .$height_condition
     .$width_condition
     .$girth_condition
     .$order_by;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
set_price != ''
```

does not evaluate to true when `set_price` is `NULL`.

I suspect you might not want spaces:

```
trim(set_price) <> ''
```

You can add `and set_price is not null` if you want, but that is unnecessary.